# Problem in saving fields to database from csv using fastercsv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, fastercsv

I am trying to save my csv data to table items which is associated with Item model.

This is what my csv have:

```
'name';'number';'sub_category_id';'category_id';'quantity';'sku'; 'description';'cost_price';'selling_price'
'Uploaded Item Number 1';'54';'KRT';'WN';'67';'WNKRT0054';'Some Description here!!';'780';'890'
'Uploaded Item Number 2';'74';'KRT';'WN';'98;'WNKRT0074';'Some Description here!!';'8660';'9790'
```

First row show the fields for items table.

Here I am using fastercsv to process my csv and paperclip to upload.

I am able to process file read content and able to fill up the field too here is the processing code:

```
def proc_csv
    @import = Import.find(params[:id])
    @lines = parse_csv_file(@import.csv.path)
    @lines.shift
        @lines.each do |line , j|
        unless line.nil?
        line_split = line.split(";")
         unless ((line_split[0].nil?) or (line_split[1].nil?) or (line_split[2].nil?) or (line_split[3].nil?) or (line_split[4].nil?) or (line_split[5].nil?))
         # I used puts to get to know about what's going on.
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[0]: #{line_split[0]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[1]: #{line_split[1]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[2]: #{line_split[2]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[3]: #{line_split[3]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[4]: #{line_split[4]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[5]: #{line_split[5]}"+"*"*50 
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[6]: #{line_split[6]}"+"*"*50
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[7]: #{line_split[7]}"+"*"*50
         puts "*"*50+"line_split[8]: #{line_split[8]}"+"*"*50

         @item = [:name => line_split[0], :number => line_split[1], :sub_category_id => line_split[2],:category_id => line_split[3],:quantity => line_split[4], :sku => line_split[5], :description => line_split[6], :cost_price => line_split[7], :selling_price => line_split[8]]
         puts "#"*100+"@item is: #{@item.inspect}"+"#"*100

         end
         end
        end
     redirect_to import_path(@import)
  end
```

but the problem is that when it process it and when I check the **@item in console** it looks like this:

```
####################################################################################################@item is: [{:quantity=>"\000'\0006\0007\000'\000", :name=>"\000'\000U\000p\000l\000o\000a\000d\000e\000d\000 \000I\000t\000e\000m\000 \000N\000u\000m\000b\000e\000r\000 \0001\000'\000", :sku=>"\000'\000W\000N\000K\000R\000T\0000\0000\0005\0004\000'\000", :cost_price=>"\000'\0007\0008\0000\000'\000", :number=>"\000'\0005\0004\000'\000", :selling_price=>"\000'\0008\0009\0000\000'\000", :sub_category_id=>"\000'\000K\000R\000T\000'\000", :description=>"\000'\000S\000o\000m\000e\000 \000D\000e\000s\000c\000r\000i\000p\000t\000i\000o\000n\000 \000h\000e\000r\000e\000!\000!\000'\000", :category_id=>"\000'\000W\000N\000'\000"}]####################################################################################################

####################################################################################################@item is: [{:quantity=>"\000'\0009\0008\000", :name=>"\000'\000U\000p\000l\000o\000a\000d\000e\000d\000 \000I\000t\000e\000m\000 \000N\000u\000m\000b\000e\000r\000 \0002\000'\000", :sku=>"\000'\000W\000N\000K\000R\000T\0000\0000\0007\0004\000'\000", :cost_price=>"\000'\0008\0006\0006\0000\000'\000", :number=>"\000'\0007\0004\000'\000", :selling_price=>"\000'\0009\0007\0009\0000\000'\000", :sub_category_id=>"\000'\000K\000R\000T\000'\000", :description=>"\000'\000S\000o\000m\000e\000 \000D\000e\000s\000c\000r\000i\000p\000t\000i\000o\000n\000 \000h\000e\000r\000e\000!\000!\000'\000", :category_id=>"\000'\000W\000N\000'\000"}]####################################################################################################
```

Can anyone kindly tell me why am I getting this kind of string instead of simple string I entered in my csv file? And because of this it's not being saved into the **items** table too, I have tried all possible formats but nothing seems to be working. I want  `:name => "Uploaded Item Number 1"` instead of `:name=>"\000'\000U\000p\000l\000o\000a\000d\000e\000d\000 \000I\000t\000e\000m\000 \000N\000u\000m\000b\000e\000r\000 \0001\000'\000"`  . Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this ruby 1.9? its a guess, but it could be a unicode thing. BTW, why are you doing the split yourself?

Comment: @lal00 yes it is ruby 1.9. Without dong split I was not getting the data of a row.

Comment: Try to parse the file with 
    
    FasterCSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", :col_sep => ';') do |row|
      # use row here...
    end

Comment: +1 @lal00 It's also working thanks for this. But the string is still is coming in the same way I mentioned above :(

Comment: Instead of inspect use item.to_s()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After punching my head on to the wall and getting frustrated with this issue, I figured out that it was my CSV file that was not in proper format (was in UTF16le) and when I made an another csv file in UTF-8 encoding, I get the break through. Though I'm left with one more issue which is the string that comes is like this: `:name => "'Uploaded Item number 1'"` So when it saves into the database the column contains the data is: 'Uploaded Item number 1' . Do you have any idea how can I do it to like this: `:name => "Uploaded Item number 1"` ?